# Trim trailing newline from pasted text in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I don't like the trailing newline to be added to my history so I often need to type a backspace before enter. I want to know that is there a way to automatically do this (delete the trailing newline).

I don't want to disable bracketed paste as well since sometimes I need to edit the pasted command before submitting it.

Reproduce:

Triple click the code block below and then you will select the whole line including a trailing newline.

```
cd /tmp
```

Copy and paste it to your ZSH, it won't be executed unless you disabled bracketed paste. Now view the history file by

```
cat $HISTFILE | tail -3
```

and you will see something like this:

```
: 1646582294:0;cd /tmp\

: 1646582296:0;cat $HISTFILE | tail -3
```

If you press UP and you will see the newline is reserved.

My zshrc file can be found [here](https://github.com/QuarticCat/dotfiles/blob/main/zsh/zshrc.zsh). I'm sorry if I missed something.

Comment: If it isn't executed, it won't be added to your history and if you do execute it, a trailing newline will be added anyway. I must be missing something. Can you give an example we can use to reproduce this?

Comment: @terdon I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. I don't like the trailing newline to be added to my history so I often need to type a backspace before enter. I want to know that is there a way to automatically do this (delete the trailing newline).

Comment: @terdon I don't want to disable bracket paste as well since sometimes I need to edit the pasted command before submitting it.

Comment: QuarticCat please add those clarifications to your question. Bury them in comments and they can easily get overlooked

Comment: That's what I don't understand. All commands stored in history will have a trailing newline. Do you mean you have 2 trailing newlines for some reason? Are you sure this really happens? I don't see how a command can be stored with two, that would just be one command and one empty command. Please give us an example we can reproduce.

Comment: @terdon If you copy a command with a trailing newline into ZSH, by default it won't be executed due to bracket paste. If you submit this command without deleting the newline character, the history will record this newline by adding a backslash before it. I will edit the question and you can have a try.

Comment: @QuarticCat ooooooh! I'm sorry, I just understood. It seems like zsh history's mechanism will actually translate the literal newline characters to `\n` and will store them in the history!  That's... surprising. I don't use zsh much so I didn't realize it did this, since other shells do not.

Comment: @terdon, try `printf 'echo "foo\nbar"\n' | xclip -sel c`. And then paste it at the bash prompt where bracketed-paste has been enabled. You'll see you can run it, recall it from history (though the trailing newlines are gone). But if you exit bash and start a new instance, you'll see recalling it doesn't work anymore, because `bash` didn't encode that embedded newline in any way in the history file, so upon reading it, bash can't tell it's part of a single multi-line command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always redefine the `bracketed-paste` zle widget so it removes a trailing newline if any from the pasted text:

```
bracketed-paste() {
  zle .$WIDGET && LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%$'\n'}
}
zle -N bracketed-paste
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a zsh user but try putting this in your .zshrc

```
zshaddhistory() {
   setopt LOCAL_OPTIONS
   setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
   print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'##}"
   fc -p "$HISTFILE"
   return 1
}
```

That should remove all trailing newlines. Modify if needed to accomplish what you want. The trick is all in the [`zshaddhistory`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-zshaddhistory) hook.

Comment: It seems doesn't affect the internal history list. But it is good to know we can hook that. Upvoted.

Comment: I added the `fc` command to modify the internal history. Though I have no idea what effect this may have continuously pushing the stack. Might use up memory or something but in ZSH's own example on the linked page they do the same thing so... In any case this is not ideal because it hammers the history file. I looked at the zsh source and could find no way to filter the history in a proper manner. Maybe I missed something.